# info window android studio se repite ultimo marcador

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy recién aprendiendo y estoy haciendo una app en android studio en donde debe salir un mapa con diferentes marcadores, y cada uno debe desplegar un infowindow con diferente información (texto e imagen).. pero por algun error mio solo me muestra el ultimo infowindow configurado repetido en todos los marcadores que agrego, es como si sobre escribiera la info.
los marcadores los tengo agregados de la siguiente manera en la clase CajerosCer..

```
  Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.42218, -70.6105))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitrojo1)));
    Cajero c1 = new Cajero("Banco 1", "Activo", "", "direccion 1", "9:00 a 23:00", R.drawable.debitrojo1);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this), c1));

    Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.415316, -70.540559))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitverde1)));
    Cajero c2 = new Cajero("Banco 2", "Inactivo", "", "direccion 2", "9:00 a 23:00", R.drawable.debitverde1);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this), c2));

    Marker marker3 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.431447, -70.609332))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitverde1)));
    Cajero c3 = new Cajero("Banco 3", "Inactivo", "", "direccion 3", "9:00 a 23:00", R.drawable.verde1);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this), c3));

    Marker marker4 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-40.573886, -73.136952))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitverde1)));
    Cajero c4 = new Cajero("Banco 4", "Activo", "", "direccion 4", "9:00 a 23:00", R.drawable.verde1);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this), c4));

    Marker marker5 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-40.574308, -73.15902))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitverde1)));
    Cajero c5 = new Cajero("Banco 5", "Activo", "", "direccion 5","9:00 a 23:00", R.drawable.verde1);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this), c5));

    Marker marker6 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-40.578722, -73.174982))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitverde1)));
    Cajero c6 = new Cajero("Sucursal 6", "INACTIVO", "SIN INFORMACION", "direccion 6", "9:00 a 14:00", drawable.rojo1);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this), c6));


    Marker marker7 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-40.578722, -74.174982))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitverde1)));
    Cajero c7 = new Cajero("Sucursal 7", "ACTIVO", "SIN INFORMACION", "direccion 7", "9:00 a 14:00", drawable.rojo1);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this), c7));


}
```

también tengo la clase CustomInfoWindowAdapter
    class   CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

```
private static final String TAG = "CustomInfoWindowAdapter";
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Cajero c;

public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, Cajero c){
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {

    View infoWindows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_info_window_adapter, null);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_imagen1);
    img.setImageResource(c.getLayout());
    ((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre)).setText("Cajero " + c.getNombre());
    ((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_estado)).setText("Estado: " + c.getEstado());
    ((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_saldo)).setText("Saldo: " + c.getSaldo());
    ((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_ubicacion)).setText("Direccion: " + c.getDireccion());
    ((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_horario)).setText("Horario: " + c.getHorario());
    return infoWindows;
}
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;

}
```

AYUDAAA :( !!no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: usas base de datos??

Answer (score 0):

Falta asignarle el `title` y el `snippet` a tu código.
En tu xml del info windows puedes tener varias vistas como en tu caso:
Cajero, Estado, Saldo ... pero recuerda que el Adapter solo obtiene el `title` y el `snippet`.

En tu caso te recomiendo que concatenes por ejemplo cajero y estado en el `title` y los demás
en el `snippet` dentro de `onMapReady` y los separes (`split`) dentro de `getInfoWindow`.
El método `getInfoWindow` es para personalizar la info window.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    final CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter();
    mMap = googleMap;
    float zoomLevel = 13;
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);

    // concatenas usando "-" :
    String c1 = "Banco 1"+"-"+"Activo"+"-"+" "+"-"+"direccion 1"+"-"+"9:00 a 23:00"+"-"+"R.drawable.debitrojo1";
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(25.6724958, -100.2614327))
            .title(c1)   // en este caso solo use title
            //.snippet(otro string)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.debitrojo1)));
    String c2 = ....
}

private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
       View infoWindows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_info_window_adapter, null);
       ImageView img = (ImageView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_imagen1);

        // obtienes el String title y lo separas con split, son 6 items, el primero empieza en cero:
        String str = marker.getTitle();
        final String[] str2 = str.split("-"); 

        // cada uno se esos items le asignas un string y lo seteas a las vistas:
        String sNombre = str2[0];
        String sEstado = str2[1];
         .....
((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre)).setText(sNombre);
((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre)).setTextColor(BLUE);
((TextView) infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.info_window_estado)).setText(sEstado);
 ....
return infoWindows;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
return null;

}
```

Lo ideal sería usar una base de datos para la persistencia de datos y más se se van estar actualizando.